# ColdFusion form action attribute value gives error 404: The requested resource is not available

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In our ColdFusion 10 application on Windows Server 2012 we have two file1.cfm and file2.cfm files both on the root directory. The file1 has `<form action="file2.cfm," .....>` but when we click on the Submit button we get the following error:

```
**HTTP Status 404 - /file2.cfm**
________________________________________
**type** Status report
**message** /file2.cfm
**description** The requested resource is not available.
________________________________________
**Apache Tomcat/7.0.64**
```

The `exact copy of the same application works on another machine - Windows 7` with ColdFusion 10 and `IIS 7.5`

Comment: Can you do a get operation on the file? In other words can you do a simple navigation to it.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I just tried. A simple navigation `http://myDomain/file2.cfm` gives the same error.

Comment: can you cross check or share the web server configuration file and elaborate more on what have you already tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: I would bet money on this relating to a good old fashioned jakarta error http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/coldfusion-10-iis-7-5-getting-404-even-though-file-exists/

Comment: @Anurag we have application.cfc file that has not much content except for  a few lines such as a setup for ColdFusion Data Source name. We've three folders named 1,2, and 3 under C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig folder. And, we have tried changing the settings in the Virtual Directory jakarta in IIS to C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\{instance id} with {instance id} to 1, 2, and 3. For 1 and 2 we get the HTTP error 500 even on the login page. With 3 the login page works and opens the home page but issue described in the original post remains.

Comment: @TRose We've tried the solution you pointed to but still no luck. Please see my previous comments.

Comment: Is there perhaps a difference in the web.config or htaccess files? Are you re-writing URLs at any point to get rid of the file extension?

Comment: @TRose There is no web.config or htaccess file in the app directory.

Comment: Well put a stick in me and call me a corndog with a bad habit.... any other kind of message with the error? Anything in the browser's console?

Comment: @TRose No other error. One thing I noticed that when I hover over the mouse to the Submit I can see the following URL displayed on the bottom left of the browser: `http://myDomain/file2.cfm` as it should. I must admit I'm not an expert on client side debugging such as using browser's console.